# Creating advanced search with select options including acts_as_taggable tags search

Tags: ruby, forms, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm currently working on re-building a search feature, we have a basic search and an advanced search, I have a basic search form working, however, I can't seem to get an option based search working.

Here's what I have so far.

Scenario:

I need to be able to select the dropdown option and then enter my search term, here is what my form looks like
[image]

My form looks like this

```rb
<%= form_tag contacts_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class='l-inline-row-block'>
    <div class='l-inline-col'>
      <%= select_tag(:qs, options_for_select(['name', 'customers', 'suppliers', 'tags'], selected: params[:qs])) %>
    </div>

    <div class='l-inline-col'>
      <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    </div>

    <div class='l-inline-col'>
      <%= submit_tag submit_text, { class: 'no_print' } %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have the following in the controller index method

```rb
 @contacts = Contact.search(params[:qs], params[:search])
```

and the following in the model

```rb
SEARCHABLE_FIELDS = [
  'name',
  'customers_name',
  'suppliers_name',
  'tags'
]

def self.search(field, query)
  if field.present? && query.present? && SEARCHABLE_FIELDS.include?(field)
    where(arel_attribute(field).matches("%#{query}%"))
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Here is the db structure:

```
  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_account_id"
    t.integer  "supplier_account_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "salutation"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "mobile"
    t.string   "business_email"
    t.string   "private_email"
    t.date     "date_of_birth"
    t.string   "spouse"
    t.string   "address_1"
    t.string   "address_2"
    t.string   "address_3"
    t.string   "address_4"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.text     "other_information",   limit: 65535
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.integer  "updated_by"
    t.string   "contact_type"
    t.integer  "assigned_to"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.string   "web_address"
    t.string   "second_phone"
    t.integer  "prospect_strength"
    t.boolean  "obsolete"
    t.string   "url"
    t.index ["obsolete"], name: "index_contacts_on_obsolete", using: :btree
  end

create_table "accounts", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.string   "short_name",        limit: 9
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "type"
  t.string   "child_type"
  t.integer  "parent_id"
  t.integer  "position"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.decimal  "value",                       precision: 11, scale: 2, default: "0.0"
  t.boolean  "fixed",                                                default: false
  t.boolean  "allow_new_child",                                      default: false
  t.integer  "created_by"
  t.integer  "updated_by"
  t.boolean  "disabled",                                             default: false
  t.boolean  "locked",                                               default: false
  t.boolean  "restricted",                                           default: false
  t.string   "account_section"
  t.string   "description"
  t.boolean  "is_budget_account",                                    default: true
  t.boolean  "is_budget_enabled",                                    default: false
  t.integer  "sequence"
  t.index ["type"], name: "index_accounts_on_type", using: :btree
end
```

were using `acts_as_taggable` for the tags which need to be searchable.

Here is the current method that the previous search uses if this helps

```rb
def quick_search_fields
  @quick_search_fields = [
    {
      col_name: 'name',
      title: 'name',
      column_names: ['contacts.name']
    },
    {
      col_name: 'customer_name',
      title: 'customer',
      search_tables: [:customer],
      column_names: ['accounts.name']
    },
    {
      col_name: 'supplier_name',
      title: 'supplier',
      search_tables: [:supplier],
      column_names: ['accounts.name']
    },
    {
      col_name: 'tags',
      title: 'tags',
      tags: true,
      tagged: Contact
    }
  ]
end
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'contacts.customers' in 'where clause': SELECT  `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` WHERE (`contacts`.`suppliers` LIKE '%john%') ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

The advanced search tab looks like this, I'm trying not to use a gem if possible as I want to learn how best to do this, obviously there is a lot of options but I want to focus on the basic option based search for now.
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that `SEARCHABLE_FIELDS` being just an array is not enough
you are searching `Contact` only while other fields are in other tables for example in your old search when you search for `supplier` if looks for either `supplier_name` or `accounts.name` (not really sure here) but inside the supplier table

```
    {
      col_name: 'supplier_name',
      title: 'supplier',
      search_tables: [:supplier],
      column_names: ['accounts.name']
    },
```

your current implementation is searching just in the contact table which does not have the `suppliers_name` nor the `customer_name` directly
now you are able to have a workaround for this but it will need similar info to the ones in quick_search_fields

where you `joins` the supplier on the contacts table `Contact.joins(:supplier_account).where(supplier_account(s): { supplier_name: query })`

---------- **Update:**

First of all, there are a few things not consistent between your fields in the view and the one used inside your model

so let's put all field details inside the model

model:
I'm assuming your model has association between the `customer_account_id` and the `supplier_account_id` correctly set

```rb
QUICK_SEARCH_FIELDS = {
    name: {
      column_names: 'contacts.name'
    },
    customers: {
        joins_table: :customer,
        column_names: 'accounts.name' # you may need to change this to association name not really sure (e.g: `customers.name`)
    },
    suppliers: {
        joins_table: :supplier,
        column_names: 'accounts.name' # here too
    },
    tags: {
      tagged_with: true
    }
}.with_indifferent_access


def self.search(field, query)
  field = QUICK_SEARCH_FIELDS[field]
  return all unless field && query

  relation = all
  relation = relation.joins(field[:joins_table]) if field[:joins_table]
  relation = relation.where("#{field[:column_names]} LIKE ?", "%#{query}%") if field[:column_names]
  relation = relation.tagged_with(query) if field[:tagged_with]
  relation
end
```

Note: I did not understand how tags or what do you wanna do with tags so i left it out hoping you would get it

in your view let's reuse the fields defined in our model directly to avoid any mismatch

```
      <%= select_tag(:qs, options_for_select(Contact::QUICK_SEARCH_FIELDS.keys(), selected: params[:qs])) %>
```

Comment: So would it be possible to reuse the `quick_search_fields`? In regards to that join though where would that go, based on the code I have above would it be possible for you to flesh out the example more. Trying to learn how this would work as this is a legacy app I'm working on so I'm trying to modernise how this search works.

Comment: can you please then post the schema for the supplier, customer and if there is a accounts table then that too

Comment: I've added the accounts table in the same code block for the contacts schema, as for suppliers and customers there's no schemas for that

Comment: @debugabug I added an example but i do not understand how tags work so i left it out

Comment: There doe using acts_as_taggable, but I'll give the following a try

Comment: added the tagged_with condition

Comment: Do I need to change anything controller wise? Because the search just returns everything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230931/discussion-between-mshka-and-debugabug).